# Using custom tags with angular directives seems to replace all custom tag content

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an app right now and I am running into an issue it doesn't seem a lot of tutorials answer.  An example can be viewed [here](http://calebprenger.com/projects/angular).

```js
var app = angular.module('test',[])
var box = angular.element(document.querySelector('#box ul'));
var offset = 0;
app.controller('box',function($scope, $compile, $http){
  $scope.add=function(){
    offset+=1;
    box.append($compile('<user-list-item></user-list-item>')($scope));
  }

})

app.directive('userListItem',function($http, $compile){
  return{
    template:'<li ng-repeat="user in users" >{{user.f_name}} {{user.l_name}}</li>',
    restrict:'E',
    controller:function($scope){
      $http.get('http://dev.firepixel.com/high5rn/api/users&limit=1&offset='+offset).success(function(data){
        if(typeof data.output != 'string'){
          $scope.users = data.output;
        
        }
        else{
          alert('end of users')
          $('button').remove()
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#box{
  min-height:200px;
  border: 1px dashed #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">

<div id="box" ng-controller="box">
  <ul>

  </ul>
<button ng-click="add()">add</button>
</div>
</div>
```

When inserting the tag and compiling it so it renders info, the first one displays fine, but when I append another, it replaces the original one with the new one, and adds another one with the same information. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

try this :

**Script** :

```
var app = angular.module('test',[])
var box = angular.element(document.querySelector('#box ul'));
var offset = 0;
app.controller('box',function($scope, $compile, $http){
 $scope.users = [];
  $scope.add=function(){
    offset+=1;
    $http.get('http://dev.firepixel.com/high5rn/api/users&limit=1&offset='+offset).success(function(data){
        if(typeof data.output != 'string'){
          $scope.users.push(data.output[0]);     
        }
        else{
          alert('end of users')
          $('button').remove()
        }
      })

  }
})

app.directive('userListItem',function($http, $compile){
  return{
    template:'<li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.f_name}} {{user.l_name}}</li>',
    scope: {
        users : '=data'
    },
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    controller:function($scope){

    }
  }
})
```

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-app="test">

<div id="box" ng-controller="box">
  <ul>
    <user-list-item data="users"></user-list-item>
  </ul>
<button ng-click="add()">add</button>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that You assign each time a new value to users array instead pushing.

Try to replace your directive with this one:

```
app.directive('userListItem',function($http, $compile){
return{
template:'<li ng-repeat="user in users" >{{user.f_name}} {{user.l_name}}</li>',
restrict:'E',
controller:function($scope){
  $http.get('http://dev.firepixel.com/high5rn/api/users&limit=1&offset='+offset).success(function(data){
    if(typeof data.output != 'string'){
      $scope.users.push(data.output);

    }
    else{
      alert('end of users')
      $('button').remove()
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new scope for all directive: like this->

```
app.directive('userListItem',function($http, $compile){
  return{
    template:'<li ng-repeat="user in users" >{{user.f_name}} {{user.l_name}}</li>',
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{},
    controller:function($scope){
      $http.get('http://dev.firepixel.com/high5rn/api/users&limit=1&offset='+offset).success(function(data){
        if(typeof data.output != 'string'){
          $scope.users = data.output;


        }
        else{
          alert('end of users')
          $('button').remove()
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

see link : http://plnkr.co/edit/lBzTmXALihUS2l8qDJib?p=preview